# CORS, header field content-type is not allowed in preflight response, .NET React

Tags: reactjs, .net, cors

I know there's plenty of questions here about CORS but I can't make it work and I've been stuck for few days by now.

I'm working on a little React ts app and implementing API calls to a basic .NET webAPI.
I already implemented the get in the app, now I'm stuck on POST.

Here's the error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7122/api/Products/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here's React POST code

```
function postData(post: { id: number; pName: string; pDesc: string; }) {
        axios.post(uri, { post })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              })
    }
```

And here's .NET controller implementation

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ProductContext _context;

    public ProductsController(ProductContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProductDTO>> PostTodoItem(ProductDTO todoDTO)
    {
        var todoItem = new Product
        {
            Description = todoDTO.Description,
            Name = todoDTO.Name
        };

        _context.Products.Add(todoItem);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        /*return todoDTO;*/
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Here's my Program.cs where I should apply useCors() policy

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyCorsPolicy",
    policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7122", "https://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

And my simple DTO

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I'm only trying to get an Ok() response. The preflight OPTIONS request is accepted correctly but then something goes wrong with the response. No problem with Swagger or Postman, I can POST correctly from there.

I browsed for few days by now here and in .NET docs, but the proposed solutions do not work.
I did install a Chrome plugin and while testing it, it says POST should work too.
As I get it, this problem should be solved already using useCors() policy in .NET, but as shown it still persist. What am I missing?

I'm quite new to web development as can be seen, so if any other info is needed please forgive me and let me know, thanks.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar looked at the post already, asked in 2016, sadly no suggested solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `https://localhost:3000` in your policy with `http://localhost:3000` which is what your origin is.

Comment: As much as I feel dumb to admit it, this was the actual issue. Thanks alot!